# How can I make a iPhone to execute a javascript on a onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, menu

I found this code with a jQuery function to removed the `onClick` event ad replace it for an `tap` even in iPhone.  I just can't make it work.

How can I make and iPhone to execute those JavaScript  other than onclick? I try onChange and no luck neither.

```
function rebindClicks(){
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isIphone = (userAgent.indexOf('iphone') != -1) ? true : false;

if (isIphone) {
    // For each event with an inline onclick
    $('[onclick]').each(function() {
        var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
        $(this).removeAttr('onclick'); // Remove the onclick attribute
        $(this).bind("click", preventClickEvent); // See to it that clicks never happen
        $(this).bind('tap', onclick); // Point taps to the onclick
    });
}
}

function preventClickEvent(event)  {
event.preventDefault();
}

<select name="jumpMenu" class="tableBlackWhite" id="jumpMenu"   style="width:275px" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)" >
    <option value="#"><font color="#FF0000" size="3">אנא בחר שיר להשמעה</font></option>
    <option onclick="javascript:ajax('/Songs/01.php','SongsContentArea')" value="#"> »  נייס באלמו</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:ajax('/Songs/02.php','SongsContentArea')" value="#"> »  מאתונו</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:ajax('/Songs/03.php','SongsContentArea')" value="#"> »  פיה אסי</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:ajax('/Songs/04.php','SongsContentArea')" value="#"> »  טליוסאמה</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this line:

```
$(this).bind('tap', onclick); // Point taps to the onclick
```

is passing a string instead of a function, since a string is coming from the `attr()`. You can try using an `eval` here, but it's really hacky. Like this:

```
$(this).bind('tap', function() { eval(onclick); }); // Point taps to the onclick
```

Comment: is not responding in an iphone